# Internal error on BigQuery from MySQL external_query aggregating a case expression returning a datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an MRE below that generates an internal error in Big Query. The issue arises when running a MySQL statement as a parameter to the BQ external_query function. The SQL works fine in MySQL. This is the expression that causes the problem, i.e. max of a case expression returning a datetime.

`max(case when t.code = 'BALANCE' then t.date else null end)`

Casting the null side of the case expression as datetime doesn't help. There are no issues when the result of the case expression is an int or bigint in MySQL.

The error is: “An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 3144498”

And from the BQ logs:

```
severity: "INFO"   
textPayload: "... [Note] Aborted connection 737652 to db:... (Got an error reading communication packets)"
```

This MRE does not require a schema, just a BQ connection to a MySQL Cloud instance (v5.7) (#StandardSQL). There 3 cases here; the first 2 generate an internal error, and the last is a workaround. Toggle the comments as necessary and run. Again, the quoted MySQL SQL works as expected in MySQL.

```
select *
  FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("your_mysql_connection_string",
'''
select t.id as transactionID
       -- Aggregation 1: Generates internal error
      ,max(case when t.code = 'BALANCE' then t.date else null end) as maxDate
--       -- Aggregation 2: Generates internal error
--       ,max(case when t.code_id = 999 then t.date else null end) as maxDate
--       -- Aggregation 3: Workaround the internal error
--      ,from_unixtime(max(case when t.code = 'BALANCE' then unix_timestamp(t.date) else unix_timestamp(cast(null as datetime)) end)) as maxDate
  from (
          select 1 as id, 'BALANCE' as code, 999 as code_id, current_timestamp() as date union all 
          select 2, 'BALANCE' as code, 999 as code_id, current_timestamp() as date
       ) t
 group by t.id
;''')
;
```

This looks to me like some kind of bug in the BigQuery/MySQL interface. The queries work as expected in MySQL and are basic aggregation statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree, sounds like a bug - so you might want to submit it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)

Meantime, below is much simpler workaround - just wrap your mysql query with `select * from (...) t` as in below example

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("your_mysql_connection_string", '''
select * from (
    select t.id as transactionID
        -- Aggregation 1: Generates internal error
        ,max(case when t.code = 'BALANCE' then t.date else null end) as maxDate
    from (
        select 1 as id, 'BALANCE' as code, 999 as code_id, current_timestamp() as date union all 
        select 2, 'BALANCE' as code, 999 as code_id, current_timestamp() as date
  ) t
  group by t.id
) t
''');
```

Comment: Interesting. So wrapping query in an inline view somehow "hides" the "complexity" of the original query. Probably good practice to do this as a matter of course.

BTW, I like the sound of your BigQuery Mate. I must check that out next week. I'll also submit a bug report then. Thanks for the nice workaround.